# Dynamically fetch data from tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have the following code which gives all the table names and column names of a specific database in MySQL.

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = DATABASE()
order by table_name, ordinal_position;
```

So, I want to use `TABLE_NAME` and (maybe not sure yet) `COLUMN_NAME` to dynamically fetch the data of each table.

e.g. `select COLUMN_NAME from TABLE_NAME;`

I was thinking to create a procedure where I will declare 2 variables to do that, but I don't know if mysql has this kind of scoping capabilities. Apart from the scoping capabilities I think this idea is kind of silly.

The other idea I have to use some magic `JOIN` operation to do that, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Magic Join won't work here since you can't dynamically refer to a table or database within straight SQL. You can loop through the results of your query above and send to a prepared statement [(see here)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) within a procedure.

Comment: which server side language you are using?

Comment: I don't want to use a server side language. I just want to read the data using pure SQL through MySQL Workbench.